# How to insert row in a table without multiple querying max(column_name)+1?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table where data has to be inserted as like this:

```
SEQ      NAME      RUN_SL DOC_SL    DATE
1        UNIX       1       1    26/10/2019
2        UNIX       1       2    26/10/2019
3        UNIX       1       3    26/10/2019
4        ABCOP      2       1    26/10/2019
5        ABCOP      2       2    26/10/2019
6        TESLA      1       1    27/10/2019
7        LETHA      1       2    27/10/2019 
8        TESLA      2       1    27/10/2019
9        NEWBE      2       2    27/10/2019
```

The data should be inserted day wise. A user can insert multiple rows at a time. In that case the RUN_SL will be same but DOC_SL will be incremented. In order to achieve that I had to always look upon like this:

```
SELECT NVL(MAX(A.RUN_SL), 0) + 1, NVL(MAX(A.DOC_SL), 0) + 1
INTO V_RUN_SL, V_DOC_SL
FROM TEST_TBL A
WHERE A.DATE = SYSDATE;
```

Then had to insert data using a loop:

```
FOR DATA_LIST..COUNT:
 INSERT INTO TEST_TBL
 VALUES(
   TBL_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
   DATA_LIST(i).NAME,
   V_RUN_SL,
   V_DOC_SL,
   SYSDATE
 );
```

I know there will be concurrency issues regarding the NVL(MAX(Column_Name), 0) + 1. In order to achieve proper insertion how to deal with it and also seeking alternative suggestions to optimize the queries?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The old fashioned way is to use a sequence.  The new fangled way is to use `generated always as identity`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff So far I know it is supported from 12c. But I have to use 11g.

Comment: Instead of `+ 1` you can use `+ row_number() over (order by whatever)`

Comment: Your SELECT statement does not match the requirement you state. Could you start by saying in your sample data which rows were inserted together? Does RUN_SL = 1 mean the first 3 rows were inserted at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asking questions, I am going to make some assumptions:

- "DATE" is the date portion only, with the time portion at 00:00:00
- The first time today that someone inserts one or more rows, RUN_SL should be 1.
- The next time today someone inserts some rows, RUN_SL should be 2.
- Every time RUN_SL increments, DOC_SL should start over at 1.

Now some remarks:

- You use SYSDATE. If you want the date portion only, use TRUNC(SYSDATE).
- To do multiple inserts, use FORALL not FOR. FORALL will call the SQL engine once, FOR will call it once per row. Switching back and forth between PL/SQL and SQL costs a lot of CPU.
- To avoid concurrency issues, only one session at a time can do the inserts. I use a simple locking mechanism on a technical table to serialize the operations.

The code below is a simple proof of concept. The input data is hard-coded to insert 'UNIX' three times.

Best regards, Stew Ashton

```
create table test_tbl(
  SEQ number primary key,
  NME varchar2(16),
  RUN_SL number,
  DOC_SL number,
  DTE date
);
create sequence TBL_SEQ;
create table tbl_lock(n primary key check(n=1)) as
select 1 from dual;

declare
  type t_name is record(nme test_tbl.nme%type);
  type tt_name is table of t_name;
  data_list tt_name := new tt_name();

  l_run_sl test_tbl.run_sl%type;

  type tt_num is table of number;
  lt_num tt_num := new tt_num();

  procedure lock_tbl is
    l_num number;
  begin
    select n into l_num
    from tbl_lock
    for update wait 3;
  end lock_tbl;

begin
  lock_tbl;
  data_list.extend(3);
  lt_num.extend(3);
  for i in 1..data_list.count loop
    data_list(i).nme := 'UNIX';
    lt_num(i) := i;
  end loop;  
  select nvl(max(run_sl), 0) + 1 into l_run_sl
  from test_tbl
  where dte = trunc(sysdate);
  forall i in 1..data_list.count
    insert into test_tbl (seq, nme, run_sl, doc_sl, dte)
      values(tbl_seq.nextval, data_list(i).nme, l_run_sl, lt_num(i), trunc(sysdate));
end;
/
commit;
```